# How to turn off "Offers in-app purchases" on Google Play for my app

Tags: android

I've just uploaded my first app to Google Play. Its free and I have no in-app purchases.

Even that I have no in-app purchases I can still see in Google Play that there is a sentence next to the google play icon that says "Offers in-app purchases". How do I cancel it? I've searched all over the google play developer console for a place to uncheck it but couldn't found one. Also in the In-app Products tab I have gray screen that says "Your app doesn't have any in-app products yet. " So can u help me please?

Thank u in advance

Comment: make sure you don't have `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />` in your manifest

Comment: Please did you solve the issue?

Comment: @LisaAnne were you able to remove it?

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the in-app billing permission from your Android manifest and publish a new APK. It is this line in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Comment: I uploaded new apk without this permission,But playstore still showing my app is offering in-app purchase. Waiting for reply.

Comment: Seems this doesn't help (any more)

Comment: any update on this ... can we turnoff in app billing?

Comment: @Shashanksingh any luck?

Comment: @ono make sure you have also removed the billing library from your build.gradle. Check my newly added answer for a work around if you need to keep the billing library for some reason like multiple app variants.

Comment: @BipinVayalu, please clear the Play Console app cache. Or re-enter to the app page twice. It was solved problem in my case.

Answer (score 6):

Adding on to @HansKratz answer. If you have any other dependencies that add the permission such as `com.android.billingclient:billing` you will either need to remove the dependency adding the permission or explicitly remove it from your final merged manifest by adding:

`<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" tools:node="remove" />`

Comment: In my case, removing that in build.gradle file worked for me. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue recently so I'm just posting here in case someone else might still need help.
After removing any reference to Billing in my code and removing the In-App Purchase products from Google Play Console I had to pass again the Content Rating Questionnaire to make the message disappear.

Answer (score 2):

If you also want to get rid of the "Offers in-app purchases" on your Google Play app page, you need to set the status of your in-app products to inactive.

Go to your Google Play Developer Console -> Choose your app -> Click In-app Products -> Click on the in-app product and change it from active to inactive.

Note that you can't set subscriptions to inactive, once you activated them.